# New taxonomy template

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

On Drupal 7, I am trying to create a different version of the default taxonomy template file for a theme. When a user clicks on a taxonomy term, the new template file is used instead of the default one.

So far all I have managed to do is finding the correct template file name (page--taxonomy.tpl.php). The problem that I have is that the variables copied from the template file the Taxonomy module uses simply don't work, as they are obviously not being populated.

```
<?php if ($content = render($page['content'])): ?>
  <div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes.' channels-'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$term_name)); ?>">
    <?php if (!$page): ?>
      <h2><a href="<?php print $term_url; ?>"><?php print $term_name; ?></a></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="content">
      <?php print render($content); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So any variable beginning with $term is NULL. What/where do I call to populate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only template file used from the Taxonomy module is the [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7) file. If a theme implement that template file, it receive the following variables. (The list is partial; for the complete list see the documentation.)

- `$term_url`: Direct URL of the current term
- `$term_name`: Name of the current term
- `$term`: Full term object

page--taxonomy.tpl.php is a page template that Drupal uses for pages with a URL matching taxonomy/*. It is a [page template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7), for which the variables are different. In particular, it doesn't get any `$term*` variable.

#### References

- [taxonomy_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_theme/7)
- [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7)

Comment: Many thanks! That makes sense; I rename my template file taxonomy-term.tpl.php, and clear cache, and away it goes. Cheers!